# rename file which has whitespaces

Tags: shell

I want to handle this file name
 SEMAPHOREINPUT_NEW MID CHANGE REPORT_16-06-2015.xlsx

```
for file in SEMAPHOREINPUT_NEW MID CHANGE REPORT_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xlsx
 do 
mv "$file" "/home/test/${file%_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9[0-9][0-9].xlsx}.xlsx" 
done
```

But it is not converting.

I get below error

> mv: cannot stat `SEMAPHOREINPUT_NEW MID CHANGE
>   REPORT_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xlsx': No such file
>   or directory

Comment: You're missing one `]` in the `mv` line: `[0-9][0-9[0-9][0-9].xlsx` should be `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xlsx`.  I'm not clear how the `in` clause is working; I'd expect to need a backslash before each space.  Do you have just one file to rename?

Comment: I corrected it. I get the same error ..

Comment: Try passing SEMAPHOREINPUT_NEW MID CHANGE REPORT_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xlsx in " ". Or storing it in a variable before the call.

Comment: try changing `SEMAPHOREINPUT_NEW MID CHANGE REPORT_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xlsx` to `"SEMAPHOREINPUT_NEW MID CHANGE REPORT_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xlsx"`

Comment: So you want to rename `SEMAPHOREINPUT_NEW MID CHANGE REPORT_16-06-2015.xlsx` to `SEMAPHOREINPUT_NEW MID CHANGE REPORT.xlsx`? (and similar) That will wipe out every matching file except one.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quote.

That is:

```
mv 'SEMAPHOREINPUT_NEW MID CHANGE REPORT_16-06-2015.xlsx' *filename*
```